# Webpack slow on vendors compilation

Tags: webpack, source-maps

I'm using webpack to generate my bundle and vendors.

My problem is that, since I've added the vendors to my compilation, my compilation time has go from **2s to 20s** (on a slow machine, you can wait like 40s).

I've notice that *sourceMap* is generated all the time, but when I'm compiling for production, it's not optimized to generate *sourceMap* then remove them with the *Uglify* plugin. I guess I missed the point somewhere!

I've tried the `#eval` but the weight is like 4x time bigger and also isn't compiling faster (even slower).

So i'm looking for the Holy Graal:
* a way to disable sourceMap for all the compilation
* a way to disable sourceMap for only vendor (for development)
* a caching system to recompile only changed file (like when using the `--watch`)

My workflow is to use a dev env (so I use the `--watch`) on my local machine, then pushing it to my dev server with *Jenkins* that compile everything. Using watch on the server is not an option (I keep *webpack* up to date, and if I change the vendor list, I have to restart the `--watch`))

An option could be to remove vendors from my webpack config, but that would be my last try.

my *webpack.config.js*:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var jsPath = path.join(__dirname, './src/js/src/');
var vendorPath = path.join(__dirname, './src/js/src/vendors/');

// Detect environnement from package.json or command line
var prod = process.argv.indexOf("--prod") > -1;
var dev = process.argv.indexOf("--dev") > -1;

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: jsPath + 'init.js',
        vendor: [
            vendorPath + 'jquery.js',
            vendorPath + 'bootstrap.js',
            vendorPath + 'nunjucks.js',
            vendorPath + 'jquery.pickmeup.js',
            vendorPath + 'select2.js',
            vendorPath + 'select2_ext.js'
        ]
    },
    // Key for ProvidePlugin
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: vendorPath + 'jquery.js'
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './src/js/build/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    devtool: prod ? "" : "#inline-source-map",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader", query: {compact: false}}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Expose $ as global variable
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        // Concat vendors files
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            filename: "vendor.js",
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        // Set __DEBUG__ global variable
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __DEBUG__: dev
        })
    ]
    // In 'production', Uglify all JS chunked files
        .concat(prod ?
            [
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                    compress: {
                        warnings: false
                    },
                    sourceMap: false,
                    mangle: {
                        except: ['$', 'exports', 'require']
                    }
                })
            ]
            : []
        )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SourceMapDevToolPlugin directly instead of `devtool` in order to exclude certain chunks from having source maps generated. For example, if you want to exclude your `vendor` and `polyfills` bundles:

```
config.plugins.push(new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: '[name].js.map',
  exclude: ['vendor.js', 'polyfills.js']
}));
```

Comment: Very clever, I finally change the large polyfill to an on-demand polyfill, I just needed Object.assign → `"plugins": ["transform-object-assign"]`